# What is the maximum Xperia X10 memory card size?

Tags: external-sd, ram, sony-ericsson-xperia-x10

I just bought an X10 and I would like to have as large a memory card as possible. What is the largest one that works with X10? Does it work with 32 GB cards?

Comment: Has anyone successfully used a 32 GB card on X10?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I took a chance and bought a 32 GB card, class 4. It works. I believe it is a Zap or something.

---

[This post](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=657353&page=5) suggests 32 GB cards work. I'd rather someone on this site said so though.

Answer (score 1):

Acording to the specs here [GSM Arena: Sony Ericsson XPERIA X10](http://www.gsmarena.com/sony_ericsson_xperia_x10-2964.php) the X10 can take up to a 32GB microSD card.